# Magento2 How to create custom module which will be install in Vendor folder using composer

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer, vendor

I have created an extension now I want to install this using composer command in the vendor folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move your module to the vendor folder then you have to host your package to `Hosting on GitHub and Packagist` or a `private repository`.

If you want to use a private repository then you have to:

Add your repository URL  to `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": [repository url here]
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, you need to have your package [Magento package validation tool](https://github.com/magento/marketplace-tools)

Please follow https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/package/package_module.html to implement your package.

Comment: thanks, I already created git repository for this but how I can install this in vendor folder